# Gitlab Docker-in-Docker CI\CD scheme: how to pass-through volumes

Tags: docker, deployment, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, volumes

Suppose I have repository on Gitlab and following deploying scheme:

1. Setup docker and gitlab-runner with docker executor on host server.
2. In `.gitlab-ci.yml` setup docker-compose to build and up my service together with dependencies.
3. Setup pipeline to be triggering by pushing commits to `production` branch.

As it [advised in Gitlab guide](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#limitations-of-docker-in-docker) I've placed in `/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml` following lines:

```ini
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.docker]
    image = "alpine"
    volumes = ["/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock", "/cache"]
```

But volumes of my `docker-compose.yml` are completely ignored. Suppose I have git repository with following structure:

```
.gitlab-ci.yml
docker-compose.yml
user_conf.d/app.conf
```

and have volumes: `./user_conf.d:/etc/nginx/user_conf.d`. When I check on `/etc/nginx/user_conf.d` inside the container I find an empty folder intead of folder with `app.conf` inside.

So the question is: how to properly pass volumes to docker container which is started from docker executer of Gitlab runner.

P.S. Configs are as following:

**.gitlab-ci.yml**:

```yaml
image:
  name: docker/compose:latest

services:
  - docker:dind
stages:
  - deploy

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - production
  script:
    - docker image prune -f
    - docker-compose build --no-cache
    - docker-compose up -d
```

**docker-compose.yml**:

```yaml
services:
  nginx:
    image: jonasal/nginx-certbot:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file:
      - ./nginx-certbot.env
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - /etc/letsencrypt
      - ./user_conf.d:/etc/nginx/user_conf.d
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was facing the same issue on an equivalent setup (self-hosted docker executor, similar `.gitlab-ci.yml`, volume mounting via Docker compose).

I solved it via the following two changes to section `[runners.docker]` of `config.toml`:

1. Flip `privileged = false` to `privileged = true`
2. Add `"/builds:/builds"` to `volumes`

I got inspiration for both changes from [this GitLab issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/41227).

For reference, this is the full `config.toml` after the changes:

```
# config.toml

concurrent = 4

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "..."
  url = "..."
  token = "..."
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
  [runners.docker]
  tls_verify = false
  image = "docker:20.10.17"
  privileged = true
  disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
  oom_kill_disable = false
  disable_cache = false
  volumes = ["/cache", "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock", "/builds:/builds"]
  shm_size = 0
```